# Plone collection with own fields

Tags: plone

I know it is possible in plone to create content types with their own fields. 
So, is it possible to create a collection with those fields?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you like to achieve, but to answer your question:

Yes it's possible to create a collection based type with your own fields.

If you are using the DX based collection type of `plone.app.contenttypes` you can easily extend it. You also have to register your own view template, which takes care of the new fields.

Of course it is also possible to create a completely new content type.

- Check the [Collection FTI of plone.app.contenttypes](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.contenttypes/blob/master/plone/app/contenttypes/profiles/default/types/Collection.xml)
- You also need some basic knowledge about [dexterity](http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/external/plone.app.dexterity/)

Answer (score 0):

If you ment to extend the possibly choosable criteria of collections by any field-names of your portal's contenttypes and you are using the old-style collections (type_name=Topic), you can do like this, to add any of these fields as a choosable criterion to (old-style-)collections:

- Make sure, the field is registered in the portal_catalog, which you can check by accessing http://yourhost.com:8080/Plonesitename/portal_catalog/manage_catalogIndexes. If it's not already there, you need to add it via the dropdown-selection in the upper right corner, choose "Field Index".
- Make sure, the field is registered in the configuration of collections, which you can check by accessing http://yourhost.com:8080/Plonesitename/portal_atct/atct_manageTopicIndex. If it's not there, click on "All fields" in the upper right corner, search for the field-name and check the radiobox to make it available, save.
- In newer Plone-versions the old-style-collections are disabled by default, you'll probably need to enable them via http://yourhost.com:8080/Plonesitename/portal_types/Topic/manage_propertiesForm, check "Implicitly addable", save.